# how to generate all possible combinations of a 14x10 matrix containing only 1's and 0's

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm working on a problem and one solution would require an input of every 14x10 matrix that is possible to be made up of 1's and 0's... how can I generate these so that I can input every possible 14x10 matrix into another function? Thank you!

Added March 21: It looks like I didn't word my post appropriately. Sorry. What I'm trying to do is optimize the output of 10 different production units (given different speeds and amounts of downtime) for several scenarios. My goal is to place blocks of downtime to minimized the differences in production on a day-to-day basis. The amount of downtime and frequency each unit is allowed is given. I am currently trying to evaluate a three week cycle, meaning every three weeks each production unit is taken down for a given amount of hours. I was asking the computer to determine the order the units would be taken down based on the constraint that the lines come down only once every 3 weeks and the difference in daily production is the smallest possible. My first approach was to use Excel (as I tried to describe above) and it didn't work (no suprise there)... where 1- running, 0- off and when these are summed to calculate production. The calculated production is subtracted from a set max daily production. Then, these differences were compared going from Mon-Tues, Tues-Wed, etc for a three week time frame and minimized using solver. My next approach was to write a Matlab code where the input was a tolerance (set allowed variation day-to-day). Is there a program that already does this or an approach to do this easiest? It seems simple enough, but I'm still thinking through the different ways to go about this. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: You realize, of course, that there are 2**140 such matrices (about 1.4e42)?

Comment: It's just not possible to generate 2^140 matrixes, it would take more than the age of universe to do that.

Comment: What is the context? Maybe there is a way to calculate (single) random binary matrices instead?

Comment: how do python and matlab both apply to this question? I get matlab but python?

Comment: ... if you could process a billion billion such matrices per second, it would take *only* 50 million billion times the current age of the universe to deal with them all??

Comment: @josh.trow -- you do realize that python has mature array type in `numpy`?

Comment: @Tiffany instead of a brute force approach you might consider using something like monte carlo sampling or a minimization routine depending on the specific application.

Comment: +1 for trying! Next step is proving the minimum sudoku problem (http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/TAAI.2010.77) by calculating all possible grids, which is actually faster! :)

Comment: 9 answers, and most of them aren't answers at all, they're comments.  Please stop posting comments as answers in the hopes of getting misplaced votes...

Comment: @Glenn The correct "answer" is basically that this can't be done...OP really wants to do something else but is fuzzy on the details of what that is.

Comment: @Tiffany: Since your edit is so different from the original post, maybe you should start a new question (and remove the edit).

Answer (score 6):

Generating Every possible matrix of 1's and 0's for `14*10` would generate `2**140` matrixes. I don't believe you would have enough lifetime for this. I don't know, if the sun would still shine before you finish that. This is why it is impossible to generate all those matrices. You must look for some other solution, this looks like a brute force.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is absolutely impossible! The number of possible matrices is 2<sup>140</sup>, which is around 1.4e42. However, consider the following...

- If you were to generate two 14-by-10 matrices at random, the odds that they would be the same are 1 in 1.4e42.
- If you were to generate 1 billion unique 14-by-10 matrices, then the odds that the next one you generate would be the same as one of those would still be exceedingly slim: 1 in 1.4e33.
- The [default random number stream in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randstream.list.html) uses a [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) algorithm that has a period of 2<sup>19936</sup>-1. Therefore, the random number generator shouldn't start repeating itself any time this eon.

Your approach should be thus:

- Find a computer no one ever wants to use again.
- Give it as much storage space as possible to save your results.
- Install MATLAB on it and fire it up.
- Start computing matrices at random like so:

  ```
  while true
    newMatrix = randi([0 1],14,10);
    %# Process the matrix and output your results to disk
  end
  ```
- Walk away

Since there are so many combinations, you don't have to compare `newMatrix` with any of the previous matrices since the length of time before a repeat is likely to occur is astronomically large. Your processing is more likely to stop due to other reasons first, such as (in order of likely occurrence):

- You run out of disk space to store your results.
- There's a power outage.
- Your computer suffers a fatal hardware failure.
- You pass away.
- The Earth passes away.
- The Universe dies a slow [heat death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe).

---

**NOTE:** Although I injected some humor into the above answer, I think I have illustrated one useful alternative. If you simply want to sample a small *subset* of the possible combinations (where even 1 billion could be considered "small" due to the sheer number of combinations) then you don't have to go through the extra time- and memory-consuming steps of saving all of the matrices you've already processed and comparing new ones to it to make sure you aren't repeating matrices. Since the odds of repeating a combination are so low, you could safely do this:

```
for iLoop = 1:whateverBigNumberYouWant
  newMatrix = randi([0 1],14,10);  %# Generate a new matrix
  %# Process the matrix and save your results
end
```

Comment: Is there such a thing as a fast heat death? :)

Answer (score 6):

The actual implementation depends heavily on how you want to represent matrices… But assuming the matrix can be represented by a 14 * 10 = 140 element list:

```
from itertools import product
for matrix in product([0, 1], repeat=140):
    # ... do stuff with the matrix ...
```

Of course, as other posters have noted, this probably isn't what you want to do… But if it really is what you want to do, that's the best code (given your requirements) to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's unclear. One method for representing matrices is a list (eg, where element `(x, y)` in the matrix corresponds to element `x * width + y` in the list), and the code I presented will generate every 140 element list (so every 14x10 matrix) where each element is either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Still wholly unrealistic, but I'm glad that someone finally posted an answer.

Comment: It's too bad Planet Earth won't be around once the algorithm finishes :)

Comment: @josh.trow: oh, yes, entirely unrealistic. But hopefully the use of `itertools.product` will be enlightening.

Comment: @Michael McGowan: party pooper :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you **sure** you want every possible 14x10 matrix?  There are 140 elements in each matrix, and each element can be on or off.  Therefore there are `2^140` possible matrices.  I suggest you reconsider what you really want.

Edit: I noticed you mentioned in a comment that you are trying to minimize something.  There is an entire mathematical field called [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28mathematics%29) devoted to doing this type of thing.  The reason this field exists is because quite often it is not possible to exhaustively examine every solution in anything resembling a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Trying this:

```
import numpy
for i in xrange(int(1e9)): a = numpy.random.random_integers(0,1,(14,10))
```

(which is much, much, much smaller than what you require) should be enough to convince you that this is not feasible. It also shows you how to calculate one, or few, such random matrices even up to a million is pretty fast).

EDIT: changed to xrange to "improve speed and memory requirements" :)

Comment: <pedant>it might be better to use `xrange(int(1e9))` here; in Py2, `range(int(1e9))` will pre-allocate a billion-element list, which would be unnecessary</pedant>

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate over this:

```
def everyPossibleMatrix(x,y):
    N=x*y
    for i in range(2**N):
        b="{:0{}b}".format(i,N)
        yield '\n'.join(b[j*x:(j+1)*x] for j in range(y))
```

Comment: So...how are two for loops not iterating?

Comment: +1 for awesome use of new `string.format` options… but 
<pedant>in Py2, range will preallocate a list of the given size, which will quickly exhaust your memory.  `xrange` woudl be better, because it returns an iterator. Of course, in Py3 this isn't an issue…</pedant>

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to accomplish with the generated matrices, you might be better off generating a random sample and running a number of simulations.  Something like:

```
matrix_samples = []
# generate 10 matrices
for i in range(10):
    sample = numpy.random.binomial(1, .5, 14*10)
    sample.shape = (14, 10)
    matrix_samples.append(sample)
```

You could do this a number of times to see how results vary across simulations.  Of course, you could also modify the code to ensure that there are no repeats in a sample set, again depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you have a table with 140 cells and each value can be 1 or 0 and you'd like to generate every possible output? If so, you would have 2^140 possible combinations...which is quite a large number.

Comment: Yes... I'm trying to minimize something that would require changing every cell in a 10x14 table to either 1 or 0.

Comment: @Tiffany: "changing every cell in a 10x14 table to either 1 or 0" is not the same thing as generating every possible 10x14 matrix.  You really need to explain a lot more about your problem.

Comment: What is your original problem? Is there some real world problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just suggesting the this is unfeasible, I would suggest considering a scheme that samples the important subset of all possible combinations instead of applying a brute force approach. As one of your replies suggested, you are doing minimization. There are numerical techniques to do this such as simulated annealing, monte carlo sampling as well as traditional minimization algorithms. You might want to look into whether one is appropriate in your case.

Comment: I 'kind of' agree with your answer, but clearly OP should provide much more details, otherwise OP's question is just nothing but a joke. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was actually much more pessimistic to begin with, but consider:

```
from math import log, e

def timeInYears(totalOpsNeeded=2**140, currentOpsPerSecond=10**9, doublingPeriodInYears=1.5):
    secondsPerYear = 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60
    doublingPeriodInSeconds = doublingPeriodInYears * secondsPerYear
    k = log(2,e) / doublingPeriodInSeconds  # time-proportionality constant
    timeInSeconds = log(1 + k*totalOpsNeeded/currentOpsPerSecond, e) / k
    return timeInSeconds / secondsPerYear
```

if we assume that computer processing power continues to double every 18 months, and you can currently do a billion combinations per second (optimistic, but for sake of argument) and you start today, your calculation will be complete on or about April 29th 2137.

Comment: Of course now you have to figure out how to store it.  It should take roughly 24 quintillion yottabytes to hold all of the matrices :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient way to do get started Matlab:

First generate all 1024 possible rows of length 10 containing only zeros and ones:

```
dec2bin(0:2^10-1)
```

Now you have all possible rows, and you can sample from them as you wish. For example by calling the following line a few times:

```
randperm(1024,14)
```