# Representing a carbon molecule in the form of a matrix

Tags: java

[how to generate all possible combinations of a 14x10 matrix containing only 1's and 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357171/how-to-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-a-14x10-matrix-containing-only-1s)

Hello. While searching for what i wanted i found the above URL to be something useful, but not exactly helpful to my particular problem.
What i'm looking for is a way to find all possible permutations of the numbers 1 and 0 in an n dimensional square matrix. I realise that the number of such matrices will be very large and the computation time will be immense.

Hence, I wish to impose the following restrictions on the matrix.
1) The matrix should be reduced in size to an upper triangular matrix.
2) Each column must have atleast one '1'
3) The number of 1's in the matrix must be equal to or less than n- the dimension of the square matrix.
4)The total 1's in a particular column must be less than or equal to 4.

the reason i'm looking for such a code is so that i can represent a carbon molecule in the form of a matrix with each column representing one atom and each element representing a bond (1) or no bond (0) between the carbon atoms( one in the column and one in the corresponding row)

for example

```
 X 1  0  0;
 X X  1  0;
 X X  X  1;
 X X  X  X
```

where the X shows that the matrix is now only an upper triangular matrix to avoid redundancies
the rows separated by ';' and each column entry is separated by a space.
the above example shows one particular combination of 0's and 1's. what i'm looking for is a code that will give all possible combinations.

thank you.

Comment: You have failed to reduce your question to the easiest possible form; how many permutations of 1 and 0 are there in a string that is n*n long.  I believe the answer is (n*n)!  or n squared factorial.

Comment: @DwB: It's 2^(n*n)...