# how to produce every permutation of positioning 20 values of -1 in a 1-by-41 vector of ones?

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, combinations, permutation

I have written different code to produce different permutations of ones and minus ones. they work for matrixes with small dimensions:

for example:

```
S=[-1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
P=unique(perms(S),'rows');
```

produces:

```
-1  -1   1   1   1   1   1   1
-1   1  -1   1   1   1   1   1
-1   1   1  -1   1   1   1   1
-1   1   1   1  -1   1   1   1
-1   1   1   1   1  -1   1   1
-1   1   1   1   1   1  -1   1
-1   1   1   1   1   1   1  -1
 1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1   1
 1  -1   1  -1   1   1   1   1
 1  -1   1   1  -1   1   1   1
 1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1   1
 1  -1   1   1   1   1  -1   1
 1  -1   1   1   1   1   1  -1
 1   1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1
 1   1  -1   1  -1   1   1   1
 1   1  -1   1   1  -1   1   1
 1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1   1
 1   1  -1   1   1   1   1  -1
 1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1   1
 1   1   1  -1   1  -1   1   1
 1   1   1  -1   1   1  -1   1
 1   1   1  -1   1   1   1  -1
 1   1   1   1  -1  -1   1   1
 1   1   1   1  -1   1  -1   1
 1   1   1   1  -1   1   1  -1
 1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1   1
 1   1   1   1   1  -1   1  -1
 1   1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1
```

or

```
indices = nchoosek(1:41, 6);
N = size(indices, 1);
S = ones(N, 41);
S(sub2ind([N 41], [1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N].', indices(:))) = -1;
```

can produce 
a matrix of 4496388_by_41 of all the permutations of 6 minus one(-1) and 35 one(1).

these codes work for smaller dimensions but they don't work for the matrixs with larger dimensions.

my goal is to produce all permutations of 20 minus one(-1) and 21 one(1) this matrix has 269128937220 rows and 41 columns. but the following codes don't work:

```
indices = nchoosek(1:41, 20);
N = size(indices, 1);
S = ones(N, 41);
S(sub2ind([N 41], [1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N 1:N].', indices(:))) = -1;
```

or

```
S=[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
P=unique(perms(S),'rows');
```

I do a simple calculation on each permutation(each row of this matrix). if I could write each row of this matrix with for loops and then do the calculation on that row, I would be able to keep the best result and in this situation I wouldn't have to keep all these data in the memory and I wouldn't get out of memory errors from matlab.

if you know how to produce a matrix of all the permutations of 20 minus one(-1) and 21 one(1) with for loops or any other way to store them in my computer please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: You've determined that there are 269128937220 combinations. What do you intend to do with these? Say you're able to evaluate 1000 combinations every second: `269128937220 / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 = 3114.9` days! Are you sure you need to check **every possible** combination? I have the feeling that this is not the right approach for whatever problem it is that you're trying to solve...

Comment: 269128937220 rows and 41 columns. That means 80 TB of memory. Do you have that?

Comment: I think [this may be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5357213/52738).

Comment: @SardarUsama lets be clear, 80TB of RAM! not even ROM! Please ehsun, take a second to see how absurd this is.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, not necessarily 3000 days... all we need is a few hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in `Matlab` so I can't speak for all of the resources available, however, I know that your task is feasible on a standard laptop without any fancy high performance services such as https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/.

I have authored a package in `R` called `RcppAlgos` that is capable of completing this task comfortably in a few hours. Here is the code:

```
options(scipen = 999)
library(parallel)
library(RcppAlgos)

## WARNING Don't run this unless you have a few hours on your hand

## break up into even intervals of one million
firstPart <- mclapply(seq(1, 269128000000, 10^6), function(x) {
    temp <- permuteGeneral(c(1L,-1L), freqs = c(21,20), lower = x, upper = x + 999999)
    ## your analysis here
    x
}, mc.cores = 8)

## get the last few results and complete analysis
lastPart <- permuteGeneral(c(1L, -1L), freqs = c(21, 20), 
                           lower = 269128000000, upper = 269128937220)
## analysis for last part goes here
```

And to give you a demonstration of the efficiency of this setup, we will demonstrate how fast the first one billion results are completed.

```
system.time(mclapply(seq(1, 10^9, 10^6), function(x) {
    temp <- permuteGeneral(c(1L, -1L), freqs = c(21, 20), lower = x, upper = x + 999999)
    ## your analysis here
    x
}, mc.cores = 8))

   user  system elapsed 
121.158  64.057  27.182
```

Under 30 seconds for 1000000000 results!!!!!!!

So, this will not take over 3000 days as @CrisLuengo calculated but rather a conservative estimate of 30 seconds per billion gives :

```
(269128937220 / 1000000000 / 60) * 30 ~= 134.5645 minutes
```

I should also note that with the setup above you are only using `1251.2 Mb` at a time, so your memory will not explode.

```
testSize <- object.size(permuteGeneral(c(1L,-1L), freqs = c(21,20), upper = 1e6))
print(testSize, units = "Mb")
156.4 Mb ## per core
```

All results were obtained on a MacBook Pro 2.8GHz quad core (with 4 virtual cores.. 8 total).

## Edit:

As @CrisLuengo points out, the above only measures generating that many permutations and does not factor in the time taken for analysis of each computation. After some more clarification and a new question, we have that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595866/4408538) now... about 2.5 days!!!

Comment: 135 minutes if you don’t do anything with those permutations. Put something meaningful in the “your analysis here” part, and see your timing go up significantly. I have no idea what OP needs these permutations for, and neither do you. :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo , thanks for the kind words. Yes, you are correct about not knowing what analysis is going down on each permutation. When I get a chance I’ll edit my answer to make that clear.

Comment: thank you so much for the help.

the calculation includes the following operation on each row :

(S*L*S')/4

where
S is each row of this matrix(a 1 by 41 array).
S' is the transpose of S(a 41 by 1 array).
L is a 41 by 41 matrix
and the final result of each row is a single number.

do you think such calculation is possible?

Comment: @ehsun, I’ve worked out a solution, However I don’t think it would be appropriate to edit this answer or add another answer to this post. Can you ask another question in the framework of `R` with the specific computation required for each permutation?

Comment: sure thing, I'll do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594408/how-to-produce-every-permutation-of-20-one-1-in-a-1-by-41-vector-of-ones-and


this is the link to the question

Comment: @Joseph, I am new to R, When I run the code I get this error: "Error in mclapply(seq(1, 269128000000, 10^6), function(x) { : 
  'mc.cores' > 1 is not supported on Windows"
why is it and how can I solve it?
I searched some pages but I thought it might be a good idea to ask it from yourself. thanks in advance.

Comment: @ehsun, according to the documentation [mclapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html) relies on forking and hence is not available on Windows machine. You can try [parLapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/clusterApply.html), however it is a little more involved... There are several great examples out there, so I encourage you to study them.