# Conditional combinations matrixes in r

Tags: r, matrix, binary, combinations, permutation

How can I create all binary combinations of matrices with the condition that there can only be a single `1` per column and row. The example will clarify. This particular example must have 6 matrices of combinations, I am showing only the first 2.

```
c1 <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 3) #First combination
c2 <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow = 3) #Second combination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is equivalent to finding all permutations of `length = n` where `n = nrow(c1)` (or `c2` above). Using the `FUN` argument of `permuteGeneral` from `RcppAlgos` (I am the author), we can easily generate the desired outcome:

```
n <- 3L
myIdentity <- diag(nrow = n)

library(RcppAlgos)
permuteGeneral(n, n, FUN = function(x) myIdentity[x, ])
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    1    0    0
```

There are many other ways of generating the requested output. Most notably, utilizing the tried and true `combinat` package, we can get a similar result (the output will be in a different order):

```
combinat::permn(3, fun = function(x) myIdentity[x, ])
```

Now that we have reduced the problem to simply generating permutations, we can use any of the great packages (`arrangements`, `gtools`, `multicool`, `partitions`, etc.) for generating permutations to obtain our desired result with the help of `lapply`:

```
library(arrangements)
myPerms <- permutations(n)
lapply(1:nrow(myPerms), function(x) myIdentity[myPerms[x,], ])
```

Comment: your approach works well for matrix of size up to 10. For larger sizes it outputs an error:  "The number of rows cannot exceed 2^31 - 1". Do you suggest a solution? It could be made in parts.

Comment: @Alfredo_MF, now to address your comment, yes there are ways for dealing with larger cases. As it is a **[different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, I suggest you ask a new question as the approach is completely different.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will take in consideration. I saw you are an expert in combinations, if you can give me just a suggestion where to research to solve my problem before making a new question I will appreciate.

Comment: @Alfredo_MF , I’m glad I can help and I appreciate your willingness to improve. I’m currently traveling but will be able to point you in the right direction later today.

Comment: @Alfredo_MF, now to actually address your real question. Here are some excellent resources for dealing with larger cases (Disclaimer: some of thesel deal with the library that I authored `RcppAlgos`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51571526/4408538, 

https://github.com/jwood000/RcppAlgos#using-arguments-lower-and-upper,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22569328/4408538

I will note that `arrangements` is a great library for these types of operations. It is capable of producing iterable objects, so you can generate results one by one at will.

Comment: I will look up in the resources.